# How to transfer integer to UINT256 for smart contract

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am creating a faucet website for my custom token and I am having trouble specifying the amount that needs to be sent. Does someone know how to transform a INT to Uint256. Thanks in advance!

This is the code I use:

```
var FromWalletID = getCookie("WalletID")
var ToWalletID = document.getElementById('wallet_address').value
var Aantal = document.getElementById('aantal').value

EnergyContract.methods.mint(ToWalletID, Aantal).send({from: FromWalletID}).then(console.log);
```

Code from the contract:

```
contract EnergyVoting is ERC20, Ownable {
constructor() ERC20("EnergyVoting", "ENGV") {}

function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public {
    _mint(to, amount);
}
```

}

Comment: This should work, as long as is not a negative number and is smaller than an uint256 it will take the value, is this throwing an error?

Comment: HI Julissa, Thanks for your response, When I enter a number it only transfers a small amount.  For example. 0.00000000000000005

Comment: Hi Max, this is because you need to pass the amount in wei. Take a look at this converter. https://www.eth-to-wei.com/ If the user writes 5 for example you need to send 5000000000000000000 to the contract.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with big integers in front end might be tricky. I recommend you pass the parameter as a string instead of Uint256.

If you want to send 1000 of your token, this should work even if your contract accepts Uint256. Of course, you can use a variable instead.

```
EnergyContract.methods.mint(ToWalletID, "1000000000000000000000");
```

Edit: If the user writes 1000 in UI simply add 18 zeros to it and call the contract. Take a look at this converter: https://www.eth-to-wei.com/ Remember you are working with wei in the contract.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you maybe have a look at the contract if it needs changing. I added the code to the form.

Comment: It looks good. Just remember you are working with wei in your contract.

Answer (score 0):

"Hi Max, this is because you need to pass the amount in wei. Take a look at this converter. eth-to-wei.com If the user writes 5 for example you need to send 5000000000000000000 to the contract"

Comment: This is written in the answer below, I also added this to comment to your original post. You should accept the answer with the checkmark, not add a duplicate answer your own. :)